# Convert JS Object to Array Value Pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am wondering how can I convert the Key-Value pair of an Object to an Array of key Value Pair. I tried using `Object.entries(data)` but it gives me a 2D array for example if I have:

```
var o = {"name":"john", "lastname":"doe"}
```

This turns to be:

```
var a = [["name","john"],["lastname","doe"]]
```

But what I really need to have is: [EDIT] --changed to Array of object

```
var newArr = [{"name":"john", "lastname":"doe"}]
```

I have been playing around with this but no luck. Can someone walk me through this? would appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Your expected output is invalid. Arrays do not have key-value pairs, only values.

Comment: Array does not support key value pair

Comment: Be clear with the expected output

Answer (score 1):

The output format you asked for - `["name":"john", "lastname":"doe"]` is not possible because array does not support such a format. Instead we can go for array of object with each object having one key-value pair as needed - `[{"name":"john"},{"lastname":"doe"}]`

This is the code -

```
var o = {"name":"john", "lastname":"doe"}

var a=Object.keys(o).map(key=> {
  var obj={};
  obj[key]=o[key];
  return obj;
})

console.log(a);
// [{"name":"john"},{"lastname":"doe"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`["name":"john", "lastname":"doe"]` isn't valid because [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) can't have `[key, value]` pairs.

But arrays can have objects and each object can have `[key, value]` pairs.

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns `[key, value]` pairs of the object. We can access them and insert into an array.

We can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do that.

```js
var o = {"name": "john","lastname": "doe"};

var result = Object.entries(o).map(([key, value]) => {
  return {[key]: value};
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want key value pairs, they will have to be inside of objects.  So you need an array of objects like this: [{"name":"john"}, {"lastname":"doe"}]

Here's a somewhat advanced way to do it with reduce function:

```
 let newArr = Object.keys(obj).reduce((accumulator, keyInObj, index)) => {
    let keyValuePair = {};
    keyValuePair[keyInObj] = obj[keyInObj];
    accumulator[index] = keyValuePair;
    return accumulator;
 }, [])
```

- result:
- newArr = [{"name":"john"}, {"lastname":"doe"}]

[{"name":"john"}, {"lastname":"doe"}]

Or like this:

```
let obj = { name: "john", lastName: "doe"};
let newArr = [];
let index = 0;
for(let keyInObj in obj) {
     let keyValuePair = {};
     keyValuePair[keyInObj] = obj[keyInObj];
     index = index + 1;
     newArr[index] = keyValuePair;
}
```

- result:
- newArr = [{"name":"john"}, {"lastname":"doe"}]

Answer (score 0):

Array can't have `key:value` you could create an array of object to do that. Very simple way to do it.

```js
var o = {"name":"john", "lastname":"doe"};

var A = [];

for(let key in o){
   obj = {};           // create an object
   obj[key] = o[key]; // create key value pair
   A.push(obj)        // insert into Array
 }
 console.log(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch if you still want expected output then you only need to replace curly brackets to square brackets

```js
var string = '{"name":"john", "lastname":"doe"}';
string = string.replace(/\{/g, "\["); 
string = string.replace(/\}/g, "\]");

console.log(string);
```